# Group columns and collapse

Tags: excel, vba

It's possible to group certain columns in Excel with the following code.

Is it also possible to collapse (hide) that group in order to hide them when plotting the sheet?

```
Sheets("Blad2").Select
Columns("D:H").Select
Selection.Columns.Group
```

Comment: What do you mean, "...when plotting the sheet"?

Comment: while exporting the sheet to a pdf file with a seperate macro, colums D through H should be hidden, so I thought the easiest way was to group them and collapse the group afterwards, bit more userfriendly for later possible changes than just hiding the colums

Comment: Why not just add that code in to your separate macro that's exporting the sheet? Or create a separate sub and call that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a column within the Group:

```
Set ws = ActiveSheet
ws.Columns(4).ShowDetail = False
```

Alternatively, define a `Custom View` with the columns hidden and switch to this view. Define another View with the columns visible so that you can easily switch between the Views.

```
ActiveWorkbook.CustomViews("test").Show
```

---

You could also create a macro that does the hiding and unhiding of columns.